# How to draw a graph from text file in bash?

Tags: bash, graph, curses

I have a text file, each line of which contains two blank separated fields: *x* and *y*.

```
1 0
10 29
5 2
```

Now I would like to see the graph of *y = f(x)*, where *x* and *y* are taken from the file.

I would prefer a `curses` picture in a terminal but it can be a picture in any graphics format as well.

What is the easiest way to do it in `bash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a very funny possibility. The thing I'm going to show you here is probably not what you're looking for, it's probably not optimized, it's probably a whole bunch of junk, but it's really funny. (I'm not expecting any upvotes for it).

This script more or less plots a `*` at each point the coordinates of which are given in a file (given as first argument of the script). It computes the number of rows and columns of your terminal (using the command `stty`, if you happen to have it installed, it's good, otherwise, well, it's not going to work).

```
#!/bin/bash

isnumber() {
   for i; do
      [[ "$i" =~ [[:digit:]] ]] || return 1
      [[ "$i" =~ ^[+-]?[[:digit:]]*\.?[[:digit:]]*$ ]] || return 1
   done
   return 0
}

die() {
   echo >&2 "$@"
   exit 1
}

[[ -n $1 ]] || die "You must provide an argument"

xarray=()
yarray=()

# Read file input
while read x y _; do
   isnumber "$x" "$y" || continue
   xarray+=( "$x" )
   yarray+=( "$y" )
done < "$1"

# Check that we have at least one point
(( ${#xarray[@]} )) || die "Error, there's no valid point inf file \`$1'"

# Compute xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax:
read xmin xmax ymin ymax valid < <(
   bc -l < <(
      echo "ymin=${yarray[0]}; ymax=${yarray[0]}"
      echo "xmin=${xarray[0]}; xmax=${xarray[0]}"
      for i in "${!xarray[@]}"; do
         echo "y=${yarray[i]}; if (ymax<y) ymax=y; if (ymin>y) ymin=y"
         echo "x=${xarray[i]}; if (xmax<x) xmax=x; if (xmin>x) xmin=x"
      done
      echo 'print xmin," ",xmax," ",ymin," ",ymax'
      # This will tell us if we have xmin<xmax and ymin<ymax
      echo 'print " ",(xmin<xmax)*(ymin<ymax)'
   )
)

# Check that xmin<xmax and ymin<ymax
(( valid )) || die "Error, ! ( (xmin<xmax) && (ymin<ymax) )"

# Get terminal's number of rows and columns
IFS=' ;' read _ _ _ _ nbrows _ nbcols _ < <(stty -a)
((nbrows-=1))
((maxcols=nbcols-1))
((maxrows=nbrows-1))

# Create an array full of spaces:
points=()
for ((i=0;i<nbrows*nbcols;++i)); do points+=( ' ' ); done

# Put a '*' at each x y in array points
while read r c; do
   printf -v X "%.f" "$c"
   printf -v Y "%.f" "$r"
   points[X+Y*nbcols]='*'
done < <(
   bc -l < <(
      echo "xmin=$xmin; dx=$maxcols/($xmax-xmin)"
      echo "ymax=$ymax; dy=$maxrows/(ymax-($ymin))"
      for i in "${!xarray[@]}"; do
         echo "print (ymax-(${yarray[i]}))*dy,\" \",(${xarray[i]}-xmin)*dx,\"\n\""
      done
   )
)

# Now, print it! The clear is not mandatory    
clear
printf "%c" "${points[@]}"
```

Call the script `plot_file_in_terminal` (or maybe a shorter name).

You can try it, it's very funny, with a Mandelbrot set: the following script generates an M-set (you can give the number of pixels for the x and y coordinates as input, well, figure out a few things by yourself):

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
   echo >&2 "$@"
   exit 1
}

nbx=${1:-100}
nby=${2:-100}
Nmax=${3:-100}

[[ $nbx =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && ((nbx>5)) || die "First argument (nbx) must be an integer > 5"
[[ $nby =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && ((nby>5)) || die "Second argument (nby) must be an integer > 5"
[[ $Nmax =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && ((Nmax>5)) || die "Third argument (Nmax) must be an integer > 5"

xmin=-1.5
xmax=1
ymin=-1
ymax=1

bc -l <<EOF
for (k=0;k<$nbx;++k) {
   for (l=0;l<$nby;++l) {
      x0=k*($xmax-($xmin))/($nbx-1)+($xmin)
      y0=l*($ymax-($ymin))/($nby-1)+($ymin)
      x=x0
      y=y0
      isin=1
      for (i=0;i<$Nmax;++i) {
         if(x^2+y^2>1) {
            isin=0
            break
         }
         xn=x^2-y^2+x0
         y=2*x*y+y0
         x=xn
      }
      if(isin) print x0," ",y0,"\n"
   }
}
EOF
```

Name it `genMandelbrot` and use it as `./genMandelbrot > Mset` or `./genMandelbrot 100 50 > Mset` if your terminal is more or less 100x50. Then:

```
./plot_file_in_terminal Mset
```

Nice, eh?

If you want a sine function (say from 0 to 2*pi):

```
bc -l <<< "for (i=0;i<400;++i) { x=i*6.28/400; print x,\" \",s(x),\"\\n\" }" > sine
```

Then call:

```
./plot_file_in_terminal sine
```

## Outputs

### Mandelbrot Set (in 80x24)

```
                                                        **
                                                    **********
                                                  ***********
                                             *  *************** *   *
                                    *********************************** ****
                                    **************************************** *
                                **********************************************
                              **************************************************
         **************       **************************************************
       ******************** ****************************************************
 **  **************************************************************************
****************************************************************************
 **  **************************************************************************
       ******************** ****************************************************
         **************       **************************************************
                              **************************************************
                                **********************************************
                                    **************************************** *
                                    *********************************** ****
                                             *  *************** *   *
                                                  ***********
                                                    **********
                                                        **
gniourf@somewhere:~/cool_path$
```

### Sine (in 80x24)

```
                *********
             ****       ***
           ***             **
          **                 **
        **                    **
       **                       **
     ***                         **
    **                            **
   **                               **
  **                                 **
 **                                   **
*                                      **                                      *
                                        **                                    **
                                         **                                 **
                                           **                              **
                                            **                            **
                                             **                          **
                                              ***                      **
                                                **                    **
                                                 ***                ***
                                                   ***            ***
                                                     ***       ****
                                                        ********    
gniourf@somewhere:~/an_even_cooler_path$
```

In your OP you mentionned "the easiest way of doing"... well, you can notice, this solution it's not exactly a one-liner.

#### Edits.

- Robustness: check that `xmin!=xmax` and `ymin!=ymax` so as to not divide by 0
- Speed: Computing `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` in the same `bc` instance.
- Speed: Don't use `tput` anymore, it was retarded and too slow! Instead, build an array of points (each field contains a space or `*`).

#### Todos.

- Lots of stuff to have something we can actually work with confortably. This exercise is left to the reader.

Comment: +1 splendid use of available resources, I can imagine spending entire minutes in 1985 exploring the complexities of the Mandelbrot figure on my VT100!

Comment: @msw It makes us feel like pioneers, like Mandelbrot who on March 1, 1980 got [this picture](http://paulscottinfo.ipage.com/art-of-maths/4mandelbrot/FirstMandelbrotSet.gif) (it's the only one I could find quickly using google). If you happen to have the book _The Beauty of Fractals_, you'll find a nice article from B. Mandelbrot with a copy of his first picture (Figure 57 p. 152).

Comment: The plot needs a third argument for each point to vary the character printed. I am really not going to waste time doing it. Really.